# Illinois and anonymous tips?

Tags: search-and-seizure

In Illinois if an anonymous tips is made to state police, will they search or raid an individuals car/property?

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

If the tip is that there are pictures proving that a minor consumed alcohol 10 years ago, probably not. If the tip is that there's a kidnapped child being tortured inside, more likely.

In either event, they would probably seek to build up some independently obtained evidence to enable them to obtain a warrant based on probable cause. An anonymous tip *might* be enough, depending on how detailed it was and whether there were any objective indicators of reliability, but it's not a sure thing.